# What kind of comparison does the period cause here?

Tags: sas

I am working through a SAS program that's already running in PROD. I've encountered a statement I can't seem to find an answer on. I've *searched* through the [documentation on the WHERE expression](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000999255.htm) and it doesn't *seem* to address what I'm seeing below:

```
start_date eq .
```

What is it comparing `start_date` against when using the `.`?

**EDIT:** I've also searched through the [documentation on date time functions](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_intervals_sect014.htm) and it doesn't address it either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.` represents a missing or "null" *numeric* value. Recall that dates are [simply pretty numeric values](http://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm) counting the number of days since January 1, 1960.

Basically, it would seem that your `WHERE` clause is filtering records where start_date is not defined.

See [Representing Missing Values](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001653386.htm)

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer, I had just figured that out myself and was adding my own answer. No need to do that now because you verified my own research. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks. I've been struggling to get past 6k all day. ;)

Comment: I remember hitting that milestone myself. The next one that was a real milestone was 10K :D

Answer (score 6):

For most cases, a somewhat better way to represent this is to use the `missing` function:

```
where missing(startdate);
```

SAS not only has multiple missing values (`.A` `.B` ... `.Z` `._` as well as `.`) but of course also has character missing (`' '` or any number of spaces).  `startdate eq .` only picks up the one case.  In 99% of cases this is identical, but the missing function is not only more clear but covers that extra 1% (as well as working equally well for character values).

Comment: Thank you @Joe! I'd recently started using `missing()` for those exact reasons. I appreciate having confirmation that my reasoning is solid and not founded in faulty logic.